# Show resultset of psql queries in the CLI rather than nano

Tags: postgresql, raspberry-pi, psql, raspberry-pi2

I have two raspberry pi's; both with postgres-installed databases.

On one pi, when I'm in the `psql` command line and do something like `select * from "User";` it shows me the results in the shell/stdout.

When I'm on the other pi and type the same `select * from "User";`, it shows the output in `nano`, and I have to hit `Q` to escape and go back to the command line interface.

How do I remove the editor setting in `psql` to just show the output of the query in the command line interface?

I've found documentation to set the editor to something (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html) but I don't want to set the editor to anything, just have it print out (so I don't have to hit `Q` every time)

Comment: You have probably defined the environment variable `PAGER`   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-ENVIRONMENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run in psql

```
\pset pager off
```

or put this line into your .psqlrc file. then pager won't be used no matter how large output is.